# Priority in constraints of image over label

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints

I have a label and a pic under it. I want both of them to fill the entire screen but neither of them should have a fixed height. The label's height is variable, it depends on the length of its text. Is there a way to set constraint priority on the image, and only if the label needs more space, it expands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first set the Constraints for the label.
Align to Left, Top and Right with 0 space.

Than set the Constraints for the ImageView.
Align to Left, Bottom, Right and the Label in Top.

Now you give your Label the ContenthuginH property to 751 and your ImageView the ContentCompressionResistance to 249.

I am not sure if you need to set a min Height for the Label. But what you need is numberOfRows = 0. The min height can be archived with setting the height to 20 or greater.

Hope this helps. Have fun coding :)

Comment: Thanks! But it stills show me a yellow exclamation mark error. Any possible way i can get rid of that?

Comment: what does the warning says? Maybe i forgott something ... :D

Comment: frame will be different at run time.

Comment: I fixed it. I needed to set a minimum height. Thanks anyways.